# Why curl get http_code 200 from goole instead of yahoo?

Tags: curl, proxy

In my local environment:

```
debian@debian:~$ curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:10800 -s  -w "%{http_code}\n" -o /dev/null www.google.com
200
```

I can access google.com with socks5 proxy.

```
debian@debian:~$ curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:10800 -s  -w "%{http_code}\n" -o /dev/null www.yahoo.com
301
```

Why can't access yahoo.com with socks5 proxy then?